# How to execute start script in Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I want to create new image from jdk, build it, it works; when I run my new imag, it return container id, but can't get the process-info when `docker ps`,this is my dockerfile:

```
# specified jdk version
FROM openjdk:7-jre
# env
ENV APP_HOME /usr/src/KOAL-OCSP
ENV PATH $APP_HOME:$PATH
# copy my app in .zip to /usr/src
COPY myapp.zip /usr/src/
# unzip copy file
RUN unzip /usr/src/myapp.zip
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
#port
expose 80

#run the setup script of my app when start container 
CMD ["service.sh" "start"]
```

`service.sh` is a setup script is my app root-file, I wish the script can auto execuced when run the new self-build image.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the container has executed and exited successfully. The container will stay alive as long as the processes that you have started using the `services.sh` script is still running.

In your case, the `services.sh` has executed and exited, thus causing the container to exit.

To view all containers, use `docker ps -a`

**Update**:

The error  `/bin/sh: 1: ./service.sh: not found` indicates that the `services.sh` script is not found under `$APP_HOME` inside the Docker image. Make sure you add it under `$APP_HOME` using

```
ADD `service.sh` $APP_HOME
```

Comment: `docker ps -a`, it shows exit(127), I try run image again, it shown` /bin/sh: 1: ./service.sh: not found`, maybe I should put my script in the /bin/sh?

Answer (score 0):

```
CMD ["service.sh" "start"]
```

The above is not valid json, it's missing a comma in the the array, so docker will execute it as a string which will fail since `["service.sh"` will not be found as a command to run.

If you use `docker ps -a` you will see a list of all containers, including exited ones. From there, you can use `docker logs $(docker ps -lq)` to see the logs of the last container you tried to run. And you can `docker inspect $(docker ps -lq)` to see all the details about the last container it tried to run, including the exit code.

To get past your current error, correct your syntax with the missing comma:

```
CMD ["service.sh", "start"]
```

---

For the next problem you are seeing, a "not found" error can indicate:

- The command doesn't exist inside your container (at the expected location). In your scenario, make sure it is included in /usr/src/KOAL-OCSP that you unzip in your image.
- The shell script does exist, but calls a binary on the first line that doesn't exist in your image. E.g. if you call `#!/bin/bash` but only have `/bin/sh` in your container. This also happens when you edit the files on a Windows system and have `^M` linefeeds that become part of the name of the binary that the container is looking for (`/bin/sh^M` instead of `/bin/sh`).
- For binaries, this can happen if executable you are running has library dependencies that do not exist inside your container. For example, if you build on a glibc environment and run the container with a musl libc environment of Alpine, this same error message will appear.